# How can I increase the policy limits when I stream multiple cloudwatch log group to one lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup a lambda function to be triggered by many cloudwatch log groups. In order to do that, I added the invoke function permission on log group `aws lambda add-permission` and add subscription as lambda as destination `aws logs put-subscription-filter`. There are hundreds of log groups I need to stream to one lambda which makes the lambda trigger policy very big.

There two commands in this flow `aws lambda add-permission` and `aws logs put-subscription-filter`. I need to run these two commands per each log group. I added 46 cloudwath log groups as trigger for the lambda but when adding the 47th I got an error.

The error I got was this command:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name $AGGREGATOR_NAME \
    --statement-id add-permission-$lambdaName --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
    --principal logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com \
    --source-arn $logArn
```

```
An error occurred (PolicyLengthExceededException) when calling the AddPermission operation: The final policy size (20623) is bigger than the limit (20480).
arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-2:***
```

Is there a way to get around of that?
Is this a right way to stream hundreds of log groups to one lambda?

I have tried to use `wildcard` in the command but got a validation error.

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name $AGGREGATOR_NAME --statement-id $ID --action lambda:InvokeFunction --principal logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com --source-arn "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/hello*:*"

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the AddPermission operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/hello*:*' at 'sourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z0-9-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+:([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1})?:(\d{12})?:(.*)
```

Comment: It seems like the error is NOT resulted from the `aws logs put-subscription-filter` api call. Is it resulted from `aws lambda add-permission` instead?

Comment: yes, you are right, the error was from add-permission. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to get around of this is to utilize wildcard in `--source-arn`. By doing this, you don't need one lambda resource-based policy for each CloudWatch log group. Of course, the simplest way is to allow **all** log groups to execute `lambda:InvokeFunction`. In this case, you just need

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name $AGGREGATOR_NAME \
    --statement-id add-permission-$lambdaName --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
    --principal logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

Notice that the `--source-arn` is removed.

Comment: I'd like to use wildcard to restrict log groups but got validation error. I have posted on my qusetion

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao You must specify the region and the account number. For example, `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/aws/lambda/hello*:*`